# How to detect CLOSE_WAIT on socket in C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, status

I'm writing TCP client and I want to reconnect immediately when connection will be broken (i.e. server is restarted). I want to restart connection as soon as possible, even if there is no data to send over this socket. I see in netstat that connection is in CLOSE_WAIT state, but there is no error from select, getsockopt or getpeername.
I know that I can try to write something to socket, but this connection is only for reading.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv):

> **Return Value**
>
> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` means a `FIN` was received from the peer. That will cause `select()` to report the socket is readable, and then `recv()` will return 0. This is the "orderly shutdown" that the man page is referring to.